# Audio Amplifier Power Usage

Tags: amplifier, audio

I'm looking to add an audio amplifier to a circuit, in this case the [TPA0211](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa0211.pdf) in 5V mode for a full 2W of output.

My rather dumb question is this: I should expect **at least** 400mA of current draw from the amplifier, given the 2W output at 5V into a 4ohm load, correct? I don't see current draw listed on the DS, other than the supply current of 6mA, so I'm wondering if its amperage draw is implied given the output power and input voltage are stated.

Comment: 2 W Into 4Ω From 5V Supply

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - Thanks, I updated my original question with the load impedance.

Comment: I didn't look long at the datasheet. But the 6 mA max in BTL mode is the quiescent class-AB current without a signal and without a load and with 2.5 V. At 5 V, the quiescent current will be higher, perhaps 9-10 mA as a typical value. I'd plan for more -- say 100 mW quiescent. (The quiescent current is just what keeps it functioning.) When a load is attached and you supply a signal, it will be directing large swings of voltage (and current compliance) at the output and then it will be dissipating lots more power. Look at Table 2 for dissipation under load.

Comment: I²=P/R=2/4=0.5 thus I = 0.5 A pk

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - Aha -- Now I get what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: @t3ddftw The peak voltage required (for RMS power) is \$V_+=\sqrt(2\,P\,R)\$. In your case, this means \$4\:\text{V}\$. In BTL mode, there are two amplifiers, one in anti-phase of the other one. This is how the amplifier can manage to do it with only one \$5\:\text{V}\$ rail. This means that the peak current will be \$1\:\text{A}\$ (4 V through 4 Ohms.) That assumes you drive this all the way to its max capability. (When, luckily, more power will be in the load and less dissipated in the IC.) RMS current is about \$710 \:\text{mA}\$ at full power of \$2\:\text{W}\$ into \$4\:\Omega\$.

Comment: @t3ddftw This is a particularly good datasheet since it includes work product needed to understand power dissipation in the IC for varying situations. You should read the text carefully, above Table 2.

Comment: Also, note in Table 3 at average power of 2W out the maximum ambient is –3°C while the hotspot is 100'C

Comment: @jonk - Perfect, thank you! I will certainly work through the equations above Table 2.

Comment: @t3ddftw Bear in mind that for typical music (there are whole papers analyzing music), you will be using only about an average that is 20% of the peak power capability. This means more dissipation in the IC, less in the speaker. So for a 2 W capable system, you'll probably average 400 mW into the speaker, or so. Stuff that into the efficiency equation to work out the IC dissipation.

Comment: @jonk - The IC is going to be use to drive speakers from a hands-free telephony system, so it's going to be even more under-utilized than with music. Thanks for the heads up, too!